# Why does a stopped application disappear from Tomcat manager in TomEE?

Tags: tomcat7, apache-tomee

I have found a strange behavior using Tomcat manager in TomEE (version 1.6.0-plus on 64 bit Linux system).

When I have stopped an application from the manager it was disappeared immediately from the application's list. Even the standard applications.

Only when I have shutdown the tomcat server and started again the apps was displayed again.

Is this a normal behavior or is it a mistake in TomEE?

I have found something here:

http://osdir.com/ml/users.openejb.apache.org/2012-03/msg00024.html

but it did not explain my situation.

Comment: easy to check what I have described above just call /manager/text/stop?path=/docs and /manager/text/start?path=/docs the first call return OK and the second call return FAIL with context does not exists ... I do not understand ... in Tomcat everything works good

Answer (score 0):

that's a bug

opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1136

trunk is up to date so if you feel like building tomee yourself you can try it right now